# Getting "Error: unknown account at Object.InvalidResponse" when appication is connected to private network using metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask, web3-providers, meteor

My Contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Awards {
  address public owner;
  string  public name1;
  string  public name2;
  string  public name3;

  function Awards() {  
    owner = msg.sender;
    name1 = "Avinash";
    name2 = "Balaji";
    name3 = "Mohit";
  }

  modifier OnlyOwner() {
    if(owner ==  msg.sender) {
       _;
    }
    else {
       throw;
    }
  }


  function setAward1(string s) OnlyOwner {
    name1 = s;
  }

  function setAward2(string s) OnlyOwner {
    name2 = s;
 }

  function setAward3(string s) OnlyOwner {
    name3 = s;
  }

}
```

I deployed my contract on Local private node.

I run my geth node by using following command:

```
geth --datadir "filepath" --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpccorsdomain "*" --networkid 1234 --mine --minerthreads 1 console
```

In Javasacript , I connected my application front-end with local node using web3:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

I successfully connected my front-end. I could even access public state variables name1, name2 and name3. But when I called `setAward1()`, `setAward2()` or any other function, I got this error:

> Error: unknown account at Object.InvalidResponse.

I called function like

```
myContract = web3.eth.contract(AbiArray).at(contractAddress);

myContract.displayAward(username, function(err,res) {
  console.log("In display Award");
  if(!err) {
    console.log("winner is" + res);
    TemplateVar.set(template,"winnerName",res);
  }
  else
    console.log(err);
});
```

Please help me!!! Thank you in advance.

Comment: displayAward function is not in contract. Can you share the exact way you are trying hit the setAward1() function?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm struggling to fix this issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

The `displayAward()` method have to appear in the smart contract. Then if you are using web3 1.0.0, it should be used this way:

```
myContract.methods.displayAward(username).send({from: account_address})
.on('transactionHash', function(hash){

})
.on('receipt', function(receipt){

})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){

})
.on('error', console.error);
```

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id15